BigQuery Continuous Queries for outbound CDC
I am trying to figure out how BigQuery Continuous Queries work. I'm interested in whether they can be used for BigQuery outbound CDC. I need to capture and respond to data change events in a BigQuery table.
I created the following BigQuery Continuous Query:
INSERT INTO `myproject.test.dst_table`
SELECT
  id,
  name,
  age
FROM `myproject.test.src_table`;

Right after starting this query, the data from the src_table was successfully copied to the dst_table. So far so good.
But if, for example, I update a row in the src_table
UPDATE `test.src_table`
SET Name = 'Alex'
WHERE Id = 2;

immediately after that, the number of records in the dst_table almost doubles. A new row with the update information arrives, along with many other rows that I didn't update. Is this the correct behavior of BigQuery Continuous Queries, and if so, how can they be configured properly to only send the information that I updated without including the rest of the rows that weren't affected at all during the UPDATE?
Based on this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/78572235/1219755, it seems that BigQuery Continuous Queries can be used for BigQuery outbound CDC, but how should they be configured correctly for this purpose?
Expected behavior: after starting a BigQuery Continuous Query, all existing data is replicated from the src table to the dst table, and then only new incoming changes are replicated to the dst table.
I also just closed the tab for my active Continuous Query in the GCP Web Console for BigQuery, and now I can’t find it anywhere to, for example, stop it. Where can I find it?

For the question on stopping a continuous query ... my thinking is that we should be able to query INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS and filter on running jobs and find its JobID.  We should then be able to submit a request to cancel that job which would stop it.
